# ruby watir chromedriver does not load

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, watir

Just installed Ruby in a fresh new laptop with version 2.4.1-2 (x64) on Windows 10.

Installed Nokogiri and Waitr.

Downloaded Chromedriver and added the location to PATH (both system and user).

When I run the code from sublime:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

I get the error message:

```
'binary_path'
```

What should I try next to solve this problem? trying with firefox gives me the same error

Comment: Try putting `chromedriver.exe` in the `bin` directory of your ruby installation.

Comment: Install the Google Chrome browser too. Only Chrome webdriver is not sufficient, since the driver uses the browser. For Mozilla, do you use geckodriver? Providing more verbose error message might be helpful too.

Comment: @orde Hey that worked! Thanks!